# page working well on local host but not Heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My app works perfectly on my local host.  When I launch the app to heroku, I am getting the dreaded "We're sorry, but something went wrong..." message on a certain page.  This page works fine on my local host.

Here is my heroku log for that request.

```
2018-12-15T00:52:49.151152+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/leagues/5" host=guarded-peak-32026.herokuapp.com request_id=11b8da33-7361-4549-bab2-1a78d5bdb087 fwd="73.196.32.111" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=28ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
```

I'm not sure what the error is or how to fix it.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you ran `$ heroku run rake db:migrate`?

Comment: yes.  All other pages work fine, it's just a show page to a certain model throws an error and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Can you type heroku logs -t and copy paste what you got